# System.NotSupportedException: No data is available for encoding 65001

Tags: c#, encoding, json.net, asp.net-apicontroller, json-serialization

I have a python script making GET request using aiohttp by 10 threads simultaneously, webservice is implemented by ASP.NET Web API. I got about five 500 errors after 100000 calls for the same data(same url), the 
following is the error message. 65001 is the codepage for UTF-8, obviously our system supports 65001, even if our system doesn't support 650001, all the requests should fail, I don't know why only five of them fail.
I'm getting the same data using same url, so it's not data problem.
I have search this problem everywhere but found noting. It has been torture more than a week. Can anyone help me?
Jason.net v11.0.2

> b'{"type":"JsonSerializationException", "reason":"Error getting value
>   from \'BodyName\' on \'System.Text.UTF8Encoding\'.",
>   "details":"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error getting
>   value from \'BodyName\'  on \'System.Text.UTF8Encoding\'. 
>   ---> System.NotSupportedException: No data is available for encoding 65001.  For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.\r\n    at
>   System.Text.Encoding.GetDataItem()\r\n    at
>   System.Text.Encoding.get_BodyName()\r\n    at GetBodyName(Object
>   )\r\n    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object
>   target)\r\n  at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object
>   target)\r\n

Comment: Did you log the offending JSON when it occurred?

Comment: @mjwills thanks for reply,how can I do that ,serialization is done by framework

Comment: @mjwills I think this error happened when getting basic info of encoding ,has nothing to do with data

Comment: What does the c# data model you are serializing look like on the server side?  Do you have an instance of an [`Encoding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx) somewhere in your data model itself?  Can you provide a complete traceback or a [mcve]?

Comment: @dbc serialize object is System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.  Property causing problem is SupportedEncodings which is UTF8Encoding

Comment: @Ted - you're serializing [`JsonMediaTypeFormatter`](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/Formatting/JsonMediaTypeFormatter.cs) itself over the wire?  That's a little unusual, since `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` isn't really intended to permanently contain application data.  May I inquire why?

Comment: @dbc we are serializing system.net.http.objectcontent, it’s part of it. This is for trace purpose